# Running Jemdoc on Windows

Tags: python, html, mathjax, markup, jemdoc

I'm re-installing Jemdoc+MathJax on my new drive, since I've used it to generate my personal website for the past couple of years. This is a Python program that uses a simple markup language to generate websites, but with the benefit that it has good capabilities for math equations using LaTeX. I'm putting links to [the original Jemdoc site](https://web.archive.org/web/20231021022155/https://jemdoc.jaboc.net/), [Jemdoc+MathJax site](https://www.mit.edu/%7Ewsshin/jemdoc+mathjax.html), and [Jemdoc+MathJax Github](https://github.com/wsshin/jemdoc_mathjax) for reference.

So far I have downloaded the Jemdoc+MathJax files from Github, installed Python 2.7, and placed the "jemdoc.py" file in the main Python folder. When I navigate to the folder containing my jemdoc files to build the pages, I encounter the following issues:

- If the page doesn't have math, then it builds, but has the "page generated by jemdoc" footer, instead of a "page generated by jemdoc+MathJax" footer. This happens even when I use the mysite.conf file from Jemdoc+MathJax.
- If the page has simple equations, the page generates, but again doesn't use MathJax, instead generating small images for the webpage.
- If the page has more complicated mathematical symbols, then the webpage fails to be built. I've isolated that to the jemdoc.py file not appropriately adding the "\usepackage" commands when building TeX code.

The results I used to generate were quite pretty, [like on this page](https://personal.math.vt.edu/awmurphy/research.html). Overall, I'm just unsure which of these issues are even the relevant ones (if any of them even are), and I'm unsure what to try next since I'm not getting any big errors to copy here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem through the following steps:

1. To ensure that you are actually running [Jemdoc + MathJax](https://github.com/wsshin/jemdoc_mathjax) instead of just Jemdoc, when you open the core Jemdoc Python script in notepad, word search "mathjax" to confirm that you have the right Python script.
2. Once you have confirmed from Step 1 that you have the correct Jemdoc Python file, put that Python file in the same folder as the Jemdoc markup scripts. I had it in the main Python2.7 files folder, which wasn't being run.

Now I can finally continue on towards my dream of being that one professor with a webpage that looks like it's from 50 years ago.